# how to add action dynamically for multiple checkbox on android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

In my project rows are added dynamically to the table depending on selected items from database. This table contains a column with checkbox

How can I set action for each checkbox that are added dynamically ? The table looks like this

> ```
>     column1        column2          column3
>      id1            data1             checkbox1
>      id2            data2             checkbox2
>     .
>     .
>     .
>     .
>     .
>     .idn            datan             checkboxn
> ```

Then I want to set action for all selected checkbox and the no of checkbox not defined that changes on every activity..

```
  CheckBox  check[i]= new CheckBox(this); 

    check[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            //code
        }
    });
```

Is it possible to use this logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is:

1. As you create each checkbox, give it a unique tag by using `setTag(Object tag)` method.
2. Set the same `OnClickListener` for each checkbox.
3. Inside `onClick(View v)` method, get the tag by using `v.getTag()`. This way you will know which checkbox was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes.

```
FrameLayout yourlayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
    CheckBox[] check = new CheckBox[10];
    check[0] = new CheckBox(this);

    yourlayout.addView(check[0]);

    check[0].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hi, this is working fine", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

I don't know what kind of layout you are using, but this example works for me.

Edit: as said above, setting a tag is a nice way to know what checkbox was pressed.