# How to use setOnCheckedChangeListener for multiple checkbox [Dynamic View]

Tags: java, android, android-checkbox

i'll create a one dynamic view. in this view i can design one dynamic view with **5 CheckBox**

i'll try below code for dynamic view :

```
private void chkdynamic() {
        final String name[] = {"Credit Card", "Debit Card","Bank Deposit","in-app Purchase", "PayPal"};
        /*int Array_Count=0;
        String[] Str_Array = new String[0];

        Array_Count = Str_Array.length;*/

        for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++)
        {

            final View v = new View(this);
            v.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 5));
            v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.border_gray));

            LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
            row.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            row.setId(i);
            row.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            final CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(activity);
            checkBox.setId(i);
            checkBox.setText(name[i]);
            checkBox.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray_text));
            checkBox.setButtonDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.chk_btn));
            checkBox.setPadding(20,60,0,60);
            checkBox.setTextSize(20);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );
            params.setMargins(60, 0, 0, 0);
            checkBox.setLayoutParams(params);
            row.addView(checkBox);
            row.addView(v);
            ll_dynamic.addView(row);
        }
    }
```

as per the above code 5 checkbox created as per the name length.

My question is Now **How to i `setOnCheckedChangeListener` for checkbox**

if i check `CheckBox` one then other `CheckBox` Uncheck how to this possible in dynamic view.

please suggest me any solution.

Comment: please give me a reason of down vote. if any info is not available then i can provide you. Thank you down voter. :)

Comment: Go with `Recyclerview`

Comment: No no i don't want to use recyclerview. becoz it's not comparably every time all Checkbox is show. it's a depend on response.

Comment: Implement listener outside the for loop. In for loop add tags to all the checkboxes and set the listener. In the listener check for the tags to identify the clicked checkbox.

Comment: can you please provide me any example how to i do this @Rohit5k2

Comment: this behavior is not natural for CheckBox. That should be RadioButtons

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add action dynamically for multiple checkbox on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23287982/how-to-add-action-dynamically-for-multiple-checkbox-on-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

LinearLayout ll_dynamic;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ll_dynamic=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.hhh);
    final String name[] = {"Credit Card", "Debit Card","Bank Deposit","in-app Purchase", "PayPal"};
    /*int Array_Count=0;
    String[] Str_Array = new String[0];

    Array_Count = Str_Array.length;*/

    for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++)
    {

        final View v = new View(this);
        v.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 5));

        LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
        row.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        row.setId(i);
        row.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        final CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
        checkBox.setId(1000+i);
        checkBox.setText(name[i]);
        checkBox.setPadding(20,60,0,60);
        checkBox.setTextSize(20);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        params.setMargins(60, 0, 0, 0);
        checkBox.setLayoutParams(params);
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < name.length; j++) {
                        if (buttonView.getId() != 1000+j) {
                            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)ll_dynamic.findViewById(1000+j);
                            chk.setChecked(false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        row.addView(checkBox);

        row.addView(v);
        ll_dynamic.addView(row);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: update code  woking for me, you just need to checkbox.setid(1000+i); ,, add code below checkBox.setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: didn't work it's give me a error `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.chk.setChecked(boolean)' on a null object reference`

Comment: from above code, you can figure it out why my code working fine and you getting issue

Comment: awesome it's work for me but i think you remove some code in my code ???